# Could not set unknown property 'transitive' for project ':core' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm working on a java project that uses an old gradle version (1.12). Now I'm upgrading gradle to a newer version (4.4) to be able to use Kotlin. I've been resolving the dependencies problems and everything seems to be ok excepting a property called transitive which appear to be valid on version 1.12.

This is the piece of code giving me troubles:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':core') {   
    transitive = false //Here
  }
  // bunch of dependencies below
}
```

Any ideas of how to get the same result in a newer version of Gradle?

Comment: It would be still the same thing as 1.12, you can see doc here for the latest Gradle. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 11):

Try this..

```
compile(project(:your-library-name)) {
    transitive=true
}
```

Hope it helps.